# Looping through all comboboxes in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i am trying to create a simple WPF Application which just has comboboxes and a submit button.
what i want to do is,
when i click the button,
my function should loop through all the Comboboxes and get their Content.

My XAML -

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ComboBox2"  > // the name goes from 2 to 50
  <ComboBoxItem  IsSelected="True">Y</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>N</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>NA</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

this is my onclick function

```
private void Submit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LinkedList<String> allnos = new LinkedList<string>();
            for (int i = 2; i < 12; i++)
            {
                ComboBoxItem Item = (ComboBoxItem)Combobox+"i"+.SelectedItem; // this will not work, how should i get it?
                allnos.AddLast(Item.Content);
            }
        }
```

HOW DO I loop through all the comboboxes to get the selected values??
Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have all your components in some parent component, you could do this:

```
foreach(UIElement element in parent.Children)
{
    if(element is ComboBox)
    {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)element;
        ComboBoxItem Item = cb.SelectedItem; 
        allnos.AddLast(Item.Content);
    }
}
```

Comment: a simple linq query should do all the work :

var contents = (from child in Grid.Children.OfType<ComboBox>()
         select ((ComboBoxItem) child.SelectedItem).Content).ToList();